# RXJS/Typescript cast to observable of type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I currently have a function that returns a Observable with multiple types, i want this to be casted to specific type using generics. I wonder how i can do this?

Currently i have this:

```
  findByCorrelationId<T>(correlationId:string, removeAfter = false): Observable<T> {
    return this.effected$.asObservable().pipe(
      map((x) => x.find((y) => y.correlationId === correlationId)),
      filter((x) => x !== undefined),
      first(), // Required to fire "finalize()"
      switchMap((x) => of(x?.data as T)),

      finalize(() => {
        if (removeAfter) { this.removeByCorrelationId(correlationId); }
      }),
    );
  }
```

But i get the following error:

```
Conversion of type 'ProductVersion | ProductVersion[] | undefined' to type 'T' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'ProductVersion | ProductVersion[] | undefined'.ts(2352)
```

It says i can cast it to "unknown" before casting to type, but is there any "cleaner" way to do this ?

Comment: what is the data type of `x` ? it's complaining at `x?.data` right?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar It can be in this case: 'ProductVersion | ProductVersion[] | undefined', i want to be able to tell exactly which of those i want it to be cast to. Yes.

Comment: i'm not sure if it will work, but can you try : `findByCorrelationId< T extends ProductVersion | ProductVersion[] | undefined>` ... just a hunch tho

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with this function, but more of how it is invoked in your app. Can you share how you are using this function? It should be the part of your app dealing with `ProductVersion` and `ProductVersion[]`.

Comment: Also, you can change `x?.data as T` to `x!.data as T`. This should remove `undefined` from the error. It is also more accurate as we know `x` is defined since it passed your `filter()` check.

Comment: About the undefined check, using a guard would be more appropriate and rule out the fact that x can be undefined once it's passed the filter

Answer (score 0):

## Why this error is correct

The error you're getting is right, so you definitely do not want to cast to unknown first.

```ts
interface ProductVersion {
  correlationId: string;
  data: number
}

class Remake{

  effected$: Subject<ProductVersion[]>;

  constructor(){
    this.effected$ = new Subject<ProductVersion[]>();
  }
  
  removeByCorrelationId(correlationId: string){
    // Do something
  }

  findByCorrelationId<T>(correlationId:string, removeAfter = false): Observable<T> {
    return this.effected$.pipe(
      map(x => x.find(y => y.correlationId === correlationId)),
      filter(x => x !== undefined),
      first(), // Required to fire "finalize()"
      map(x => x.data as unknown as T),
  
      finalize(() => {
        if (removeAfter) { this.removeByCorrelationId(correlationId); }
      }),
    );
  }
}

const testClass = new Remake();
testClass.findByCorrelationId<Boolean>("HelloWorld").subscribe(v => {
  // Typescript beleives that --- (parameter) v: Boolean ---
  // But really, v has type --- number --- because ProductVersion's data field is a number
  // This is because you broke the type system.
});
```

---

Casting to

```ts
findByCorrelationId< T extends ProductVersion | ProductVersion[] | undefined>`
```

is also wrong. Consider that if `T = ProductVersion[]` this expects `findByCorrelationId` to always return `Observable<ProductVersion[]>`

```ts
const testClass = new Remake();
testClass.findByCorrelationId<ProductVersion[]>("HelloWorld").subscribe(v => {
  // Typescript beleives that --- (parameter) v: ProductVersion[] ---
  // But really, v has type --- number --- because ProductVersion's data field is a number
  // This is because you broke the type system.
});
```

#### You should use the correct types instead :)

In this case it looks like your function isn't actually polymorphic, but instead returns an observable that emits whatever the type of the data field is.

## Update

I'll try to explain with examples:

#### 1) Correct types

This could be written as returning `Observable<number>`, but writing it this way is fine too for the same reason we can return `any`. It's less specific/helpful but still sound (correct)

```ts
function correct(): Observable<boolean|number>{
  return of(10);
}
```

#### 2) Correct types, where either type is possible

This is not a generic function, it can return `boolean` or `number`, but the type system cannot know which will happen before calling the function. You must inspect the output at runtime in order to know what the return type really is

```ts
function correct2(): Observable<boolean|number>{
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? of(true) : of(10);
}
```

#### 3) Wrong: making this function generic

This is not longer sound. I can inhabit `T` with a `boolean`, but this function will always return a `number`. The types are lying!

```ts
function wrong<T extends boolean|number>(): Observable<T>{
  return of(10 as T);
}
```

#### 3) Also wrong: makinag function that can return more than one type generic

This is also not sound. I can inhabit `T` with a `boolean`, but this function will still return a `number` 50% of the time. No matter which type I give the generic, I **might** be wrong. The types are lying!

```ts
function wrong2<T extends boolean|number>(): Observable<T>{
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? of(true as T) : of(10 as T);
}
```

#### Correct: a function that is generic

This is sound again, as I can send in a `boolean` or a `number` and I get back what I send in. If I know what I'm sending in, then I know what I'll get back. This is a function that is generic over `booleans` and `numbers`.

```ts
function generic<T extends boolean|number>(value: T): Observable<T>{
  return of(value);
}
```

Comment: In my case the object type can only be one of the three ProductVersion, ProductVersion[], undefined. `findByCorrelationId< T extends ProductVersion | ProductVersion[] | undefined>` a way to solve this then ?

Comment: @Daniel From what you've shown here, no - that would still be wrong. I've added an update to my answer that might be helpful.